# the use of "by" and "to"

Tags: differences, prepositions

I can't distinguish between the use of by and to when putting  them in such sentence:

> House prices had risen **by/to** 0.3 % in July".

Especially the meaning of *by*.

Comment: Search for a dozen or so prior questions about the use of "by" with percentages.

Comment: Consider this example: "Interest rates have risen to 7 percent" means that interest rates have gone up from an unspecified previous rate by an unspecified amount and now stand at 7 percent. "Interest rates have risen by 7 percent" means that interest rates have gone up from an unspecified previous rate to an unspecified current amount by a percentage change of 7 percent.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about numerical values, the preposition *by* indicates the difference between a previous value and a current one. So if a house was worth $100, 000 and is now worth $103, 000 the value has

- risen by 3%

When we want to indicate the actual value after a rise or fall we use the preposition *to*:

- The value of the house rose to $103, 000.

Comment: Is this really suitable for ELU?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps would be better on ELL, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions can be tricky. Here, "by" means "in the amount of". In fact, you could just leave out the "by" in that sentence and it would mean the exact same thing. If you use "to", that means the house prices increased and then stopped at a particular value. It would mean that house prices were lower than 0.3%, then they increased, and now they are at 0.3% - obviously, this doesn't make sense in this case, since home values are in dollars, not percents.